# Apple script – replace with hyperlink in document without opening

Tags: sed, applescript

I need to replace 400+ words with different hyperlinks in a rtf- or .docx-document.

I’ve made a script using keystrokes (cmd+f, esc etc), but the script takes forever and is not stable enough.
Using `sed -i` I’m able to do a replacement of the word, but not with hyperlink. Is this possible?

```
set theFile to choose file

set original to "foo"

set substitute to "VG" 

set newlink to "https://www.vg.no"

do shell script "sed -i '' \"s|" & original & "|" & substitute & "|g\" " & quoted form of (POSIX path of theFile)
```

Comment: Can you clarify a few things? Are you using MS Word or another app? And what version? Editing/creating a link with sed in raw rtf is probably possible but I'm doubtful when it comes to docx. You could likely script Word to do this though.

Comment: Clarifying:
The end result has to be a MS word-document (.docx) (I'm Using MS Word for Mac 16.54). This document contains 400+ links which I have to check the validity of 3-4 times a year. I'm using Filemaker to hold and check the links and then populate the Word-document with an applescript from within Filemaker.
For me it would probably be OK to update an rtf-document which I then save as .docx from Word as the final stage. So the -sed-solution seemed smart and efficient. But maybe scripting Word is smarter?

Comment: Is the goal that a line in the final word doc contains the word 'VG', and that this word is also a link to the site 'www.vg.no'? And similarly for each of your 400 links? If so, then your challenge is make a hyperlink out of 'VG' in Word and I'm not sure where in your workflow you envision this. sed is generally applicable to plain text, which is why it solves half of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something specific to try:

First, create a rich text document with the word 'foo' as its content (in TextEdit, as Word's output is an abomination). Save the file in the appropriate place and run this:

```
set theFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "slink3.rtf"
set qptf to quoted form of POSIX path of theFile

set origStr to "foo"
set subStr to "VG"
set newlink to "https://www.vg.no"

do shell script "sed -i '' -e 's|" & origStr & "|" & subStr & "|' -e 's|VG|{{\\\\*\\\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \"https://www.vg.no/\"}}{\\\\fldrslt VG}}|' " & qptf
```

This expands to:

```
do shell script "sed -i '' -e 's|foo|VG|' -e 's|VG|{{\\\\*\\\\fldinst{HYPERLINK \"https://www.vg.no/\"}}{\\\\fldrslt VG}}|' '/Users/username/Desktop/slink3.rtf'"
```

The actual shell command which runs is:

```
% sed -i '' -e 's|foo|VG|' -e 's|VG|{{\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://www.vg.no/"}}{\\fldrslt VG}}|' '/Users/username/Desktop/slink3.rtf'
```

What it does is first replace the string `foo` with the string `VG`, and then replace the string `VG` with `VG` as hyperlinked text.

NB TextEdit has a preference to display the raw rtf upon opening a file rather than the formatted text. If you do this with a document containing a single word, the structure is relatively clear. I recommend against even looking at a Word-generated document.

If you do this, you will see that the raw rtf uses a single backslash but both the shell and applescript require escaping which is why the script has `\\\\`.

Incidentally, I notice that you finish your sed search with 'g' but shouldn't this only run once per line? Consider removing it.

Obviously, I don't know your entire workflow but hopefully this matches the section you have posted.